# Unity UI InputField detect enter or esc key when OnEndEdit

Tags: unity-game-engine, input-field

I'm trying to figure out how to detect the end of editing an InputField with either the 'enter' or the 'esc' key. I have a working solution, but was wondering if there's a better way of doing it (using already existing Unity stuff). Actually using Unity 4.7.1

Hereby is the actual solution:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class CustomInputField : InputField, ICancelHandler 
{
    // Action others can subsribe
    public System.Action<InputField, bool /*true: enter key, false: cancel key*/> OnCustomEndEdit = null;

    override public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData) {
        base.OnPointerClick( eventData );
        if( eventData.clickCount > 2 ) {
            SelectAll();
        }
    }


    // Need to presss 'enter' twice in order to receive this event. NOT USING IT!
    override public void OnSubmit(BaseEventData eventData) {
        base.OnSubmit( eventData );
    }

    // Need to presss 'esc' twice in order to receive this event. NOT USING IT!
    public void OnCancel(BaseEventData eventData) {
    }


    // This event happens before Unity calls the Update() funcion
    public void OnEndEdit( string value ) {
        if( Input.GetKeyDown( KeyCode.KeypadEnter ) || Input.GetKeyDown( KeyCode.Return ) ) {
            if( OnCustomEndEdit != null ) {
                OnCustomEndEdit( this, true );
            }
            Debug.Log( "Enter Key: " + this.text );
        }
        else {
            if( Input.GetKeyDown( KeyCode.Escape ) ) {
                if( OnCustomEndEdit != null ) {
                    OnCustomEndEdit( this, false );
                }
                Debug.Log( "Esc Key" );
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: dude it's almost impossible to use Unity 4.7.1 these days.

Comment: I don't think (and can't think) of a better way to do that. You could set an event based on input from somewhere else and register a method and that would be just the same. The only benefit of using .NET event over Unity event is speed, but that would only be relevant if used in Update. So, my word on it, don't change anything. And you would not gain anything really valuable in trying a different approach.